# Django GenericIPAddress field is not validating input

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-orm

Hi I have the following Django model

```
class AccessPointIPAddress(models.Model):
    '''Model for storing AccessPoint IP Addresses.'''
    ap = models.ForeignKey(AccessPoint, related_name='ip_addresses')
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datetime']
        get_latest_by = 'datetime'
```

And I am assuming that django's `GenericIPAddressField` does some string validation that a string is indeed a valid IP Address. I also read django's source and it does have some validation functions tied to `GenericIPAddressField`

But when I try to run this on django's shell:

```
# Assume that *ap* is a valid AccessPoint instance
# Notice ip_address IS NOT A VALID IP ADDRESS
>> AccessPointIPAddress.objects.create(ap=ap, ip_address='xxxxxx123123----')
<AccessPointIPAddress: ap xxxxxx123123---- 2015-05-18 12:39:25.491811>
```

I am expecting that it should raise some kind of ValueError or validation error since the given ip-address `xxxxxx123123----` is not a valid ip address.

Am I missing something here? Or is this part of django broken? Currently using Django 1.6.5

Comment: Validations only work for values entered through Forms. You can insert any value using the backend.

Comment: @Selcuk Okay, so does this mean, that I have to create my own validator? Either by overriding save method, or before calling the create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run

> See the form validation for more information on how validators are run in forms, and Validating objects for how they’re run in models. Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form. See the ModelForm documentation for information on how model validation interacts with forms.

You can override save() method and do a full_clean() on the model instance as described in the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run

or only use validator for GenericIPAddressField:

```
from django.core.validators import ip_address_validators
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        ip_address_validators('ipv4', self.ip_address)
    except ValidationError:
        return
    super(AccessPointIPAddress, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

it will use the following validator:

```
ipv4_re = re.compile(r'^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$')
validate_ipv4_address = RegexValidator(ipv4_re, _('Enter a valid IPv4 address.'), 'invalid')
```

Comment: That wont work as is though. ip_address_validators return a list of validators, but doesn't actually perform validation. Moreover, the second parameter is unpack_ipv4, and not the actual IP to check.

Comment: Not working for me as orzel stated; raises ValueError("You can only use `unpack_ipv4` if `protocol` is set to 'both'")

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me; so I looked through the source of validator and found these functions:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_ipv4_address
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


ip = "127.0.0.1"

try:
    validate_ipv46_address(ip) # Success
except ValidationError:
    print("Invalid")
```

Also for other types:

```
validate_ipv4_address(ip)
validate_ipv6_address(ip)
```